# Empty parameters in SvelteKit load function

Tags: javascript, parameter-passing, svelte

I'm trying to build a art portfolio in SvelteKit, following the [SvelteKit tutorial](https://learn.svelte.dev/tutorial/page-data). I have a page called `art/`, which has a subdirectory called `[collections]/` for various different collections of art pieces.

I'm temporarily loading data from a file called `data.js` which has the following structure:

```
export const collections = [
    {
        title: 'Crisis Vision',
        id: 'crisis-vision',
        content: '<p>crisis vision content</p>'
    },

    {
        title: 'From the Garden',
        id: 'from-the-garden',
        content: '<p>from the garden content</p>'
    },
    
    {
        title: 'As Lost Through Collision',
        id: 'as-lost',
        content: '<p>as lost content</p>'
    }
];
```

The `+page.server.js` file in `[collections]/` has the following contents:

```
import { error } from '@sveltejs/kit';
import { collections } from '../data.js';

export function load( {params} ) {
    const ret = collections.find((c) => c.id === params.id);
    return { 
        ret 
    };
}
```

The `+page.svelte` file has the following contents:

```
<script>
    export let data;
    console.log(JSON.stringify(data))
</script>

<h1>{data.ret.title}</h1>
<div>{@html data.ret.content}</div>
```

When I try to run this, I get `TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'title')`.

I believe I have narrowed this down to the `params` variable. When I take out `params.id` in the `+page.server.js` file, and directly replace it with an example from the data, say `'as-lost'`, it works as intended [as shown here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AViMP.png) (granted, every collection shows the same content). When I add `console.log(JSON.stringify(data))` to the script portion of the page file, it shows that the params object is empty.

What am I doing wrong here? I have tried to follow the tutorial at every step, and it's still not working. Please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use `[collections]` in the route path, you also have to use `params.collections`.
(Maybe make that singular)

Comment: I was bashing my head into the wall trying to figure this out for an hour! Thank you so much!

Comment: Would recommend using a debugger, then you just inspect all objects in scope. (You can accept answers using the checkmark outline to the side.)